# How do I properly initialise the input/output arguments for this C++ for openCL kernel?

Tags: c++, arguments, kernel, opencl

This is my first time writing OpenCL compute units, so I'm starting small; Here is my basic test kernel:

```c
kernel void test_kernel(global float* in, global float* out)
{
    int thread_id = get_global_id(0);
    printf("%d", thread_id);
    out[thread_id] = in[thread_id] + thread_id;
}
```

And here is the c++ code that is trying to construct buffers for the arguments and run it:

```c
...
...

cl::Kernel kernel(program, "test_kernel", &cl_error);
if (cl_error != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error - cl::Kernel - " << getErrorString(cl_error) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

cl::CommandQueue command_queue(context, device);

cl::vector<float> input_vector{ 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f };
cl::vector<float> output_vector{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
cl::Buffer input_buffer(std::begin(input_vector), std::end(input_vector), true);
cl::Buffer output_buffer(std::begin(output_vector), std::end(output_vector), false);

cl::EnqueueArgs enqueue_args(command_queue, cl::NDRange(5));

cl::KernelFunctor<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer> functor(kernel);
functor(enqueue_args, input_buffer, output_buffer);

for (const auto& value : output_vector) {
    std::cout << value << ", ";
}
```

My hope is to print the results of output vector buffer after running the kernel, which should equate to `input[n] + n`, however I'm only getting the initial `0`s that I populated the output vector with. I have tried a number of things, but to no avail as of yet so I've scaled it back for clarity. The kernel does build, and I get no errors running it, I just don't get the results I hoped for. I also can't see any of the print statement output.

For further context, my hardware is capable of up to openCL 1.2, running on macOS, and I have defined the openCL definitions to state that I'm using openCL 1.2 specifically.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in my setup code?

Comment: I have medium experience with both compute and graphics shaders with other libraries, but all the same, would it be advisable to get familiar with regular openCL before tackling C++ for openCL? Maybe I'm wrong, but C++ for openCL has more limited documentation and what not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test_kernel` looks good.

But on the C++ side, you are missing a few things:

1. Create the buffers on the device context, so OpenCL knows on the memory of what device it should allocate the memory:

   ```c
   const int N = 5;
   cl::Buffer input_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N*sizeof(float));
   cl::Buffer output_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N*sizeof(float));
   ```
2. You have to link the `Buffer` objects to the `Kernel` parameters. Otherwise, OpenCL does not know which of the buffers in memory corresponds to which of the parameters of `test_kernel`.

   ```c
   kernel.setArg(0, input_buffer);
   kernel.setArg(1, output_buffer);
   ```
3. Before you execute the kernel, you need to copy over `input_vector` from CPU memory to `input_buffer` in GPU memory:

   ```c
   command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(input_buffer, true, 0, N*sizeof(float), (void*)input_vector);
   ```

   Note: `output_buffer` in GPU memory remains uninitialized and could contain random values. Since your `test_kernel` writes every entry in `output_buffer` and dos not read any entry of `output_buffer`, you don't need `command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(output_buffer, ...)` here.
4. Execute the `kernel`:

   ```c
   const int local = 1; // GPU warp size is 32, so this should be 32 or a multiple of 32 to get full performance. For the test with N=5, I have set it to 1.
   const int global = ((N+local-1)/local)*local;
   cl::NDRange range_local = cl::NDRange(local);
   cl::NDRange range_global = cl::NDRange(global);
   command_queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, range_global, range_local);
   command_queue.finish();
   ```
5. Copy `output_buffer` from GPU memory back to `output_vector` in CPU memory:

   ```c
   command_queue.enqueueReadBuffer(output_buffer, true, 0, N*sizeof(float), (void*)output_vector);
   ```

   Note: The `true` in `enqueueReadBuffer` makes it a blocking command, meaning after this line the queue is automatically emptied and the data transfer is complete; you don't need an additional `command_queue.finish();` here.
6. The updated data is now in CPU memory in `output_vector` and can be further processed on the CPU or printed in the console.

Comment: Late reply, christmas and distractions and stuff... But that worked perfectly! Thanks muchly for your help